# Creating all children when a given module is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback

I have a Rails 3 app with the following relationship between models:

```
Course ---[ 1:n ]---> Module
```

And when an user enrolls into a `Course` I have this:

```
Enrollment ---[ 1:n ]---> ModuleStatus
```

Each `Enrollment` also always have an user and a course

**QUESTION**: How can I enforce that when an `Enrollment` is created for an user, the system goes ahead and creates a `ModuleStatus` for each of the modules that the given `Course` has?

Should I use a callback to enforce this creation?

If so, what callback is suitable here? Would it be `after_create`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, using `after_create` certainly makes sense. It would probably look something like this (obviously you can fill in the details of your modelling).

```
class Enrollment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :module_statuses

  after_create :generate_module_statuses

  def generate_module_statuses
    self.course.modules.each do |module|
      self.module_statuses.create(:the_correct_attributes)
    end
  end

end
```